# Where in Brotherhood does this screenshot of Ed and Al as children appear?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

I was wondering where I could find the episode that goes along with this screenshot. From the art style, it is definitely from Brotherhood. I have searched for a long time and couldn't find any episode that matches it.

[image: Ed and Al]

Comment: A number of websites indicate that this is a scan or show a dividing line down the middle, so it's probably from a magazine or artbook. I'll try to dig up more information about it.

Comment: It also appeared as a [postcard](http://inukarada.deviantart.com/art/FMA-Brotherhood-postcard-2-171850485), but since the aspect ratio there is off, I'm thinking this isn't the "original" image.

Comment: [This](http://gallery.minitokyo.net/view/420486?page=3) is one of the websites I was referring to with my first comment. Off the top of my head, I can't remember seeing this in the anime either, but my memory of it is too rusty.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd love to find the original source, but like you said, it doesn't seem to be from the anime. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: This is probably an original illustration, rather than a still from *Brotherhood*.**

This illustration *may* have originated from an official set of postcards based on the manga and *Brotherhood* continuity — when I ran a reverse image search for the image and included `postcard` and `episode` in the search terms, I found [an eBay page](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Fullmetal-Alchemist-Brotherhood-Postcard-Book-Art-/311759633298) where someone is (at the time of writing) selling such a set. (It seems possible to me that the illustration may have first appeared in a magazine or an earlier artbook, and that I was simply unable to locate it.)

One of the photographs in the product description shows the same image as that of the OP, and even the aspect ratio looks identical.

[image: eBay product preview]

Many illustrations in the postcard set — such as those of [Roy and Ed holding bunches of roses](http://azarashido.sakura.ne.jp/20100107/sCIMG5521.jpg), [Winry and Ed sitting back-to-back on a bed](http://azarashido.sakura.ne.jp/20100107/sCIMG5524.jpg), and [Ed in a state of undress](http://azarashido.sakura.ne.jp/20100107/sCIMG5525.jpg) — clearly do not originate from either the manga or the *Brotherhood* adaptation. Taking this into account along with my inability to recall a scene in *Brotherhood* that matches the OP's illustration, it makes sense to surmise that this is probably an original illustration, rather than a still taken from *Brotherhood*.

The eBay seller states that this postcard set was released on December 22, 2009. I am unfamiliar with *Fullmetal Alchemist* merchandise and so cannot confirm this with another source; I also do not know any details about how this postcard book was released.

Comment: It occurs to me that the Winry back-to-back with Ed illustration might have appeared in something like an OP or ED before: if that's indeed the case, drop me a comment and I'll delete that example.